# Why can't co_await return a string?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, c++20, coroutine

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Awaiter final {
    bool await_ready() const { return false; }    
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<>) const {}    
    T await_resume() const { return T{}; }
};

struct ReturnObject {
  struct promise_type {
    ReturnObject get_return_object() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() 
        noexcept { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() 
        noexcept { return {}; }
    void return_void() {}
    void unhandled_exception() {}
  };
};

ReturnObject f()
{
    auto a1 = Awaiter<int>{};
    [[maybe_unused]] auto v1 = co_await a1; // ok    
    auto a2 = Awaiter<std::string>{};
    [[maybe_unused]] auto v2 = co_await a2; // error
}

int main() { f(); }
```

See: [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/85K46zEG1)

The error message:

```
error: no suspend point info for ''co_await' not supported 
       by dump_decl<declaration error>'
   37 |     [[maybe_unused]] auto v2 = co_await a2; // error
      |                                ^~~~~~~~
```

**Why can't co_await return a string?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a compiler bug in the implementation of coroutines in GCC, as there is nothing in the current drafts of the standard prohibiting custom/composite types for `await_resume` (as can be seen when replacing string with any user-defined type).
The very same code for example [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/EsMW7Tzoz) with the latest version of MSVC using the `/std:c++latest` flag (which is no surprise, as Gor Nishanov, who prominently develops on the draft, uses Visual Studio to implement a prototype which may be the most tested implementation at the time of writing of this answer).

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this bug as well and found a workaround that can be handy for anyone stuck with gcc 11.
The trick is to add `await_transform` to the promise, this seem to fix the issue:

```
template <typename U>
U&& await_transform(U&& awaitable) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<U&&>(awaitable);
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/aTMYMfav4

Comment: This does not work if the U is not movable.

Comment: Thanks a million for this workaround! (BTW, in case it’s not obvious, the name `await_transform` is arbitrary; I renamed it `gcc_bandaid`  in my code :)